# How to add a file to <input> files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="file" id="ex_file" name="ex_file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.tif" />
```

javascript

```
fileList = [file, file,..., file];
```

I want to put this file list in the file list in `<input>`
need to work only within JavaScript.
Please teach me the way.

```
document.getElementById("#ex_file").files = fileList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it would be possible to "initialize" an `HTMLInputElement` object that way, you would effectively be able to read data from arbitrary files in the user's computer's file system, which would be considered to be a serious security breach. So I guess that's not possible.

The  element's `files` property is a read-only `FileList` container object, which contains `File` objects with data from files in the file system which were manually selected by the end user. So it's just a UI input mechanism for the end user. Nothing more.